# Replace javascript text with jquery or other in HTML code

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, text

i have my main page (index.php) with look as :

```
<?php start_session();
    ... PHP CODE ...
?>
<html>
   ... HTML CODE ...

<script type="text/javascript">
        var bscTexts =
                {
                    signup: {
                        cropPicture: 'Crop your profile picture',
                    },
                    home: {
                        noFavorites: 'You haven´t added any profiles as favorites'
                    },
                    general: {
                        errorUploading: 'Error uploading, please try again',
                        successfulUploading: 'Votre photo a bien été obtenue',
                        chooseAnotherPicture: 'Choisir une autre photo',
                        loadingMore: 'Loading, please wait...'
                    },
                    notificationBubbles: {
                        /*InterestedInYou */            1: {
                            Text: '[Name] has shown interest in you',
                            Url: "/match/interestedinme"
                        },
                        /*Match */                      2: {
                            Text: 'You and [Name] are now a match',
                            Url: "/match/matches"
                        },
                        /*WinkSent */                   3: {
                            Text: 'You have received a wink from [Name]',
                            Url: "/home/socialstream"
                        },
                        /*LovedPicture */               4: {
                            Text: '[Name] loves one of your pictures',
                            Url: "/home/socialstream"
                        }
                    }
                };
    </script>
... OTHER HTML CODE ...
</html>
```

I would like to know if is possible to replace the text (string statement) with jquery or other (dom)

for example :

if i call alert(bscTexts.signup.cropPicture); the result is popup alert with "Crop your profile picture"

i need to know if is possible after the page is loaded with jquery, javascript or other to replace  "Crop your profile picture" with french translation to obtain this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var bscTexts =
            {
                signup: {
                    cropPicture: 'Redimensionnez votre photo',
                }
</script>
```

This is for example so i need to change ALL strings.

Thank you for your helping !

Answer (score 0):

#### Why not you are setting french value initially regardless of changes after window load?

There is a function for in jquery for rewrite vars after document ready :

```
jQuery(function($){
    ... rewrite your vars...
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you will change all strings just assign the object again :

```
bscTexts = { ... };
```

if you have just the strings replace each one:

```
bscTexts.signup.cropPicture = 'new value';
.
.
bscTexts.notificationBubbles.Text = 'new value';
```

Comment: I know that so, when you look the HTML source code you see always the english text... read my comment in upper answer i left more info and details